# Significado de '(.*[^\\\\])'

Tags: regex, prestashop

Mirando los ficheros de configuración de *prestashop*, encontré una expresión regular. No sé si está completa, se usa en `prestashop\controllers\admin\AdminTranslationsController.php`

```
define( '_PS_TRANS_PATTERN_', '(.*[^\\\\])' );
```

¿Alguien sabe para qué sirve?

Answer (score 3):

Te explico, pero no recomiendo usarla para nada. Se puede utilizar:

1. Para eliminar todas las `"\"` que hay al final de la línea.

   Por ejemplo, para el nombre de una carpeta, por ejemplo convirtiendo a `"\Carpeta\Otra\"` en `"\Carpeta\Otra"`.    -    <kbd>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/REAX2F/1/)</kbd>

---

2. Para coincidir con caracteres que no tengan una barra al final.

   Por ejemplo, dentro de otra expresión regular, si es necesario asegurarse que al final no va a tener una `\` que escape al siguiente caracter (aunque es una forma realmente muy mala de hacerlo). Un caso sería si se busca texto entre corchetes, pero no se quiere que una barra al final de ese texto sirva como escape del corchete, como en:

   ```
   preg_match( '/\$array\[' . _PS_TRANS_PATTERN_ . '\]/',  $texto);
   ```

---

**Regex:**

```
(.*[^\\])
```

**Descripción:**

- `(.*[^\\])` - Paréntesis, para capturar el texto que coincidió con:

  - `.*` - Cualquier cantidad de caracteres
  - `[^\\]` - Coincide con 1 caracter, cualquier caracter que no sea una `\`.

Sea como fuere, hay mejores formas de obtener el mismo resultado. Es bastante *fea* esa expresión.
**No la uses** como ejemplo, ni para un código nuevo.

Comment: ¿No tendría más sentido utilizar `$` directamente y decir `[^\\\\]$`? `(.*[^\\\\])` estoy de acuerdo que está bastante _fea_. Además, la captura de grupo es innecesaria.

Comment: @fedorqui no es un regex completo, sino un fragmento... Pero cualquier cosa tendría más sentido que esa expresión. Está claro que quien la escribió no entendía mucho de regex.